# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Paste & Go" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for the location bar and then paste with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. But the last one is so fare away and for the Paste&Go I have to rely on the mouse again. Is there a keyboard shortcut for Paste&Go?

Apparently in 2010 [they didn't find this very important](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492544#c30):

> Access keys are not required for this, because this feature is
>   specifically being included for mouse-driven users.

Comment: There is an extension which can do it more easily and you don't need the AHK script even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modified version of [Paste and Go2](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Paste-and-Go-2.shtml) is available. To install it you have to go through some steps if you have the latest version of Firefox. Download the `.xpi` extension file on your system wherever you want to and now follow these steps.

1. Extract (unzip) the `.xpi` file. It is simply a zipped file with an `.xpi` extension, so you should be able to use something like unzip or Stuffit-expander (on Mac) to extract it.
2. Open the "`install.rdf`" file with a text editor such as Notepad. Find a tagline like this showing the "`maxVersion`" number (in this case 2.0, but it may differ depending on the extension):

   `<em:maxVersion>2.0</em:maxVersion>`
3. Change the "2.0" to "3.0.*" or whatever you need (the * covers any minor updates to release versions). That tells the installer that the version can be installed with the corresponding version number of Firefox or Thunderbird.
4. Save the changes you made to the `install.rdf` file.
5. Create a zip archive containing all the files that were in the original `.xpi` file, including your modified `install.rdf` file. Rename it to "`myExt.xpi`" or whatever you like. The crucial thing here is to use "`.xpi`" for the file extension.
6. Strongly recommended: before installing the extension, make a temporary [backup](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup) of your **profile folder** or at least of the "extensions" folder inside your profile folder, which contains the installed extensions. That way, if something goes wrong, you can revert the changes easily.
7. Finally, install the extension:  open the `.xpi` file from Firefox and it should install to install it via the "**File → OpenFile**" menu and select the `.xpi` file means the extension which you have downloaded.

**If you don't want to follow this procedure then you can use  [disable the compatibility checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/) extension.**

For more information about how to add FF extension via **File** menu see my another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/441012/86550).

[image]

As you can seee in the image I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for **Paste&Go** with open in new tab in background you have your choice.

Comment: Rather than going through the tedious process of modifying the addon, it's possible to just [disable the compatibility checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/).

Comment: Good catch, had not got that idea, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5):

You can always WRITE your own shortcut with autohotkey.

Download and install Autohotkey.
Implement this script:

```
;This will create for Windows+G combination

    #g::
    SetTitleMatchMode 2
    IfWinActive, firefox
    {
    Send ^L
    Send ^v
    Send {Enter}
    }
    return
```

Comment: hmm, that would require running the Autohotkey service all the time :/ I'd prefer it to be implemented in the browser itself.

Comment: good point...
but, i would recommend so for 2 reasons: 1. autohotkey is really light-weight. 2. You can create system wide shortcuts that will make a lot of tasks easier......just browse their script catalog and you will realize what you can do with it..

Answer (score 1):

Paste and go is up since release of FF4, right click on address bar "paste & go".. there are no keyboard shortcuts for the simple reason isn't needed, to press F6 (addressbar focus +select all), CTRL-V (paste), Enter (go) is faster than many other things shortcutted

Comment: Well, except that F6 doesn't always work as intended, for instance if you are in a frameset, you may have to press F6 multiple times to get to the address bar.

Comment: You basically just rephrased the information from my question. As I pointed out: It **is** needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it's true is just a rephrase because your question was the answer itself, and mine wanted to e a confiramtion there is not such shortcut (native) tho googling i read about addons who may help you.

Comment: @Alexandro - it is needed, as you could assign a spare key on a multimedia keyboard to do the combination. They you achieve paste and go with one single click of a keyboard key.